# Why can't Rust infer the type of a static or const?

Tags: rust

```
static MESSAGE_TYPE = "MyType";
```

does not compile, whereas

```
static MESSAGE_TYPE: &str = "MyType";
```

does. Why?

The same is true for `const`.